# When $f(x) - g(x)$ is strictly increasing, is $f(x)/g(x)$ strictly increasing under some conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that both strictly increasing, strictly convex, and positive everywhere. Is it true that if $f(x) - g(x)$ is strictly increasing, then $f(x)/g(x)$ is strictly increasing?

Intuitively it is true but when I differentiate $f/g$, I get
$$
\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^{2}}=\frac{(f'-g')(f+g)+g'g-f'f}{g^{2}},
$$

which looks like could be negative when $g'g-f'f$ is negative.

EDIT: I forgot one condition. In addition, $f-g$ crosses zero from below.

Comment: Not true. Consider $f(x) = 2x, g(x) = x.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan need some tweaking to get strictly convex and positive functions

Comment: @ayeayemaung I missed the "strictly" convex part, my bad

Comment: Try $f(x)=2e^x$ and $g(x)=e^x$

Comment: @QC_QAOA Ah nice. But I forgot one condition for my purpose, which is $f-g$ crosses zero from below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the idea of QC_AQOA.

Let assume continuity, increasing positive functions will have a limit at $-\infty$.
For $f-g$ to cross $0$ we will need $\lim\limits_{-\infty}f<\lim\limits_{-\infty}g$.

So we could start with $\begin{cases}f(x)=e^x+1\\g(x)=e^x+2\end{cases}$

But this is too restrictive as $f-g$ is constant, for that we need some $p(x)e^x$ where $p$ polynomial for instance. Though to keep positivity of $f$ and $g$ the chosen polynomial should not vanish.

I think quite a straightforward example of this is given by $x^2+a$, a few trials on a graphical tool show that $a$ should not be too small to keep convexity.

In the end I propose $\begin{cases}f(x)=e^x(x^2+9)+1\\g(x)=e^x(x^2+4)+2\end{cases}$

[image]

- $f$ red and $g$ blue are positive, increasing, convex
- $f-g$ green is increasing convex and crosses $0$
- yet $f/g$ purple is not monotonic